# Order of actions in creating a R package with devtools

Tags: r, devtools, r-package

I am currently developing a package for R. I have functions (of course), datasets, vignettes and tests. The vignettes are to be processed with `Rmarkdown` and the manuals with `Roxygen2`, finally, the tests are to be performed with `testthat` (so far everything works ok).

I would like to develop and finalize the package entirely from within R with `devtools` instructions. I would like to know the optimal order to call these functions. At this time, I use in that order

```
devtools::document("package folder")
devtools::build("package folder")
devtools::install("package folder", upgrade = "never")
devtools::run_examples("package folder")
devtools::test("package folder")
devtools::build_vignettes("package folder") 
devtools::check("package folder", cran=TRUE)
```

My question shows my lack of understanding of what these functions do precisely. Hence, a brief summary of the role of each function would be appreciated. Also, am I missing some steps? or are some function calls above unrequired?

Comment: i don't use those things, but i'm pretty sure `devtools::check()` does everything you have listed, why do you want to call them individually?

Comment: Would it be possible that by running them separately helps locating errors? In that case, would it be more convenient to run them separately. Likewise, is devtools::check doing anything beyond the previous commands?

Comment: Have you read the help pages for each of these functions? It seems like you are just asking us to regurgitate that information. Perhaps you could be a bit more clear on what exactly is causing your confusion. When asking what's "required", what "requirement" are you talking about exactly?

Comment: For example, the ``build`` command produces a tar.gz file. If I run ``install`` before, is the package installed from the tar.gz file or not? The command ``document`` generates the .Rd manual pages. If they are procesed after build, are they integrated into the tar.gz file? Same question for the vignette. The __Writing R extension__ official reference is written around the files, not around the process to obtain those files.

Comment: ... as of the *unrequired* steps: Maybe ``built`` redo the documentation by running ``document`` as well? If that is the case, then ``document`` is unnecessary.

Answer (score 1):

Chapter 2 ([The whole game](https://r-pkgs.org/whole-game.html)) of the [R package](https://r-pkgs.org/index.html) explains all in detail.
The one that you are missing yet is beneficial is load_all(), which loads your modified functions into the memory.